# Windows 10 won't boot, drive letter changed

Tags: windows-10, boot, system-recovery

Today I started my PC (running Windows 10) and it wouldn't boot and instead goes straight to repair.

Similarly running a system restore failed ("unspecified error").

I see after running bootrec /rebuildbcd that no Windows installations are identified, and all files formerly on my C: drive appear to be on E:, with C: now designated as "System Reserved" and a 100mb limit.

I tried to repair bootrec as described in [bootrec.exe Tool - How to use in Windows Recovery Environment](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/163216-bootrec-exe-tool-how-use-windows-recovery-environment.html) with no success.

Any advice on how to proceed from here would be greatly appreciated. Note I don't have a boot disc available nor a disc drive.

Comment: I know that a system reserved partition of 100 mb would cause problem with windows 10, in fact now it creates one of 500mb. But I think that since yesterday the pc worked. What specific error do you get on boot? Have you try /rebuildmbr?

Comment: After trying automatic repair, "your pc did not start correctly". Have tried all bootrec commands

Comment: What exactly do you mean it wouldn't boot. What happens when you try.

Comment: Clarified further in question: on startup windows fails to load and goes to the recovery/repair screen where I have access to command prompt and restore options (which haven't worked)